# How to sandbox code in chroot for multiple users?

Tags: python, debian, chroot

#### What am I trying to do?

I'm writing a code evaluator using chroot and python and went to hackerrank for some inspiration.

#### What I think is happening at Hackerrank?

Hackerrank creates run-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX folder for every run of a user program submission, each of these folders has a unique owner and only it's owner has read/write access to it. This means that a particular user `15307` cannot read/modify the contents of the other folders present.

#### Coming to the question

How would someone go about implementing this using chroot and python or any other language for that matter? Is it creating a user everytime?

Output of `ls -al`

```
total 140
drwxrwx--x  2 15307 15307   4096 Jun 24 19:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 root      0 118784 Jun 24 19:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 15307 15307      0 Jun 24 19:17 compile.err
-rw-rw----  1 15307 15307      0 Jun 24 19:17 error00000.err
-rw-r-----  1 15307 15307     27 Jun 24 19:17 input00000.in
-rw-rw----  1 15307 15307      0 Jun 24 19:17 output00000.out
-rwxrwx---  1 root      0    783 Jun 24 19:17 request.json
-rw-rw----  1 15307 15307     52 Jun 24 19:17 solution.py
-rw-r--r--  1 15307 15307    213 Jun 24 19:17 solution.pyc
```

Output of `ls -al /`

```
total 504
drwxr-xr-x  68 root       0 118784 Jun 24 19:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  68 root       0 118784 Jun 24 19:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 ubuntu     0   4096 Jan 25 11:41 android
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       0   4096 Apr  9 06:30 bin
drwxrwx--x   2  17450 17450   4096 Jun 24 19:08 custom-H8tFpKOEWGsc0s6lvpRk
drwxrwx--x   2  14667 14667   4096 Jun 24 19:15 custom-QiOC2dqgU3pVUlFU4ZWz
drwxr-xr-x  13 root       0   3860 Jun 24 19:08 dev
drwxr-xr-x  10 root       0   4096 May  6 05:37 etc
drwxrwx--x   2  18227 18227   4096 Jun 24 19:13 game-player1-YeDYLpA2uIqJFeZ3d97T9IuRAKoqDhyM
drwxr-xr-x   4 root       0   4096 May  6 05:37 home
drwxr-xr-x  21 root       0   4096 Jun 21 06:36 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       0   4096 Jun 21 06:36 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       0   4096 Jun 21 06:36 lib64
drwx------   2 root       0  16384 Jan 25 09:18 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   5 root       0   4096 Jan 25 14:10 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 127 root       0      0 Jun 24 19:08 proc
drwxr-xr-x   7 root       0   4096 Jun 21 10:30 root
drwxr-xr-x  22 root       0    800 Jun 24 19:08 run
drwxrwx--x   2  15307 15307   4096 Jun 24 19:17 run-1KpGsxE8tJkf4JZhNa3O
drwxrwx--x   2  19186 19186   4096 Jun 24 19:12 run-1a89kLrOIvxSKmcG8Vxf
drwxr-x---   2 root       0   4096 Jun 24 19:13 run-1tPF28PnLjSHnwiPQQKw
drwxrwx--x   2  18229 18229   4096 Jun 24 19:12 run-1z3LUuz9SddZHYtT6DXl
drwxrwx--x   2  17407 17407   4096 Jun 24 19:14 run-2KfLhB5KQJ9hFnT32apd
drwxrwx--x   2  13423 13423   4096 Jun 24 19:15 run-2kNHf7UsoOBjeQI2Tcbk
drwxrwx--x   2  13477 13477   4096 Jun 24 19:12 run-6fuBJP7ZgZfEm2k9vkZV
drwxrwx--x   2  14824 14824   4096 Jun 24 19:08 run-8MlwJE1ia8bR86MbVYi8
drwxrwx--x   2  15984 15984   4096 Jun 24 19:13 run-A3YDoqR2J9cGAhILYDqZ
drwxrwx--x   2  16989 16989   4096 Jun 24 19:16 run-AQQjyqXYSXeFZ9wzI5dy
drwxrwx--x   2  18819 18819   4096 Jun 24 19:15 run-AvAUgIkcFtieewAFZ6dZ
drwxrwx--x   2  13189 13189   4096 Jun 24 19:14 run-FldwZMBI51tvTI3bzTqf
drwxrwx--x   2  15862 15862   4096 Jun 24 19:08 run-GORpHssv6tp0WFktcKlE
drwxrwx--x   3  15041 15041   4096 Jun 24 19:14 run-GmRpaAqK23cjuC3opP6G
drwxrwx--x   2  12977 12977   4096 Jun 24 19:12 run-zlriB5scmjE0ASSjie2r
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       0   4096 Jun 21 06:37 sbin
drwx------   3 root       0   4096 Jun 24 19:08 store
drwxrwxrwt   4 root       0   4096 Jun 24 19:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 root       0   4096 Jan 25 11:36 usr
drwxr-xr-x   6 root       0   4096 May  2 16:53 var
```